# pgfGantt does not connect relations to bars

Tags: pgfgantt

I am using pgfgantt to outline a project timeline, but there is blank space along the x axis between the between the relations and the block. I would like the lines to start at the edge of the blocks. A minimal example is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\textwidth/105cm, yscale=3]
\begin{ganttchart}{150}
%tasks                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
\ganttbar[name=t1]{Task 1}{2}{21}\\
\ganttbar[name=t2]{Task 2}{21}{28+3}\\
%relations                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
\ganttlink{t1}{t2}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This outputs:
[image]

Comment: You have to give the lower limit in `\begin{ganttchart}{1}{105}`. Note `{1}`.

Comment: That is not consistent with the examples from the manual and results in the outer box having width 1. It doesn't seem to solve the arrow positioning issue either.

Comment: The image you posted doesn't correspond to the code. Are you perhaps using some outdated version of `pgfgantt`?